# Rectify images of different sizes

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, camera-calibration, matlab-cvst, 3d-reconstruction

I wanted to rectify a stereo image pair coming from two different modalities (visual and thermal). I calibrated both cameras using

```
[cameraParams,imagesUsed,estimationErrors] = estimateCameraParameters(imagePoints,worldPoints);
```

giving me a stereoParameter object, since imagePoints contains matching checkerboard points for both modalities.

To rectify, I used the following call:

```
[J1,J2] = rectifyStereoImages(I1,I2, cameraParamsStereo);
```

where `I1` is a visual image and `I2` a thermal one. Unfortunately, that gives me the error:

> Error using rectifyStereoImages>parseInputs (line 106) Inputs must be
>   of the same size and data types.
>
> Error in rectifyStereoImages (line 96) [I1, I2, interp, outputView,
>   fillValues] = parseInputs(...

The resolutions of both images are quite different (2048x1088 for visual, 384x288 for thermal). From my undertanding however, rectification in principle should still work, since it is done similarly in [this](http://www.vis.uky.edu/~cheung/doc/iccv09.pdf) paper. Honestly however, I am not sure how...

**Question:**
Is there a way in MATLAB to rectify images of different sizes? If not, is there an algorithm to do so that can be easily implemented?

Comment: have you tried making your thermal image the same size than the optical ? add empty row and columns to the right and to the bottom.

Comment: @gregswiss: With empty I suppose you mean zero values. I tried that now, but this gives me another error "Index exceeds matrix dimensions" in "Error in vision.internal.calibration.CameraParametersImpl/getValidBounds (line 860)"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `rectifyStereoImages` function requires the two images to have the same size. This is a limitation of the implementation, not the algorithm.

One thing you can do is undistort the images using the `undistortImage` function, find matching points (e.g. using `matchFeatures`), and then use the `triangulate` function to get a sparse 3-D reconstruction.

You can also try making the two images the same size, by padding the smaller image with zeros. You would need to pad the calibration images before calibration, so that everything is consistent.

Comment: sorry for my late reaction. I really want to rectify the images, so your first way does not work unfortunately. As for your second way I am confused: if I just pad the images with zeros on the right and bottom the corner points for the checkerboards will not change - so estimateCameraParameters(imagePoints,worldPoints) should give me the same results as before the padding?

Comment: That's a thought... Try it.

Comment: I did. I get the same error as before, stated in my comment from the 16th of September above. The corner points of the padded image do not change and estimateCameraParameters(imagePoints,worldPoints) does not get any information that the images changed whatsoever (were padded). Even if I use the stereo calibration app, calibrate (which now works with the padded images) and then click on "Show rectified" in an example, I get the same error.

Comment: Most likely that's because the data types are different. IR images are typically 16 bit. Convert the data type of the one image to match the other. Use `im2uint16`, or convert both to double or single using `im2double` or `im2single`.

Comment: hmm..does not seem to be the problem, both are of type uint8 when loaded with imread. Should I open a new question for this or edit my question above with a more detailed error description? Unfortunately, I probably cannot provide my image sets...

Comment: Is the non-IR image RGB?  Then the size is different: M x N x 3 vs. M x N x 1.  If that's the case, use `rgb2gray` on the RGB  image.

Comment: Ok, are you sure that the two images are *exactly* the same size and data type? Can you please double-check? Can it be that you have a different data type after padding? Also, which version of matlab are you using?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Also, if I input two images of different size or type MATLAB will output a specific error. Moreover, if I input the same image into rectifyStereoImages twice, it will also give me the error mentioned above. If you want, I can provide you with "blacked-out" versions of the images :) Oh, and I use Matlab R2015a

Comment: What specific error? If you are seeing "Inputs must be of the same size and data types.", then the images either have a different size or a different data type. Please check that just before the call to `rectifyStereoImages`. If you are seeing some other error message, please let me know.